# Gridview template column label values not readable in VB when updated it in Java Script

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, vb.net, datagridview

I am having asp.net grid view with template column fields that includes text box and label. When text box get edited its calculated value assigned to label using javascript, after submission of form when I am trying to read label's value I am getting its old value not the currently updated one, while i am getting correct values from textbox field,

I am using following code to get the values
`lblVal= TryCast(oItem.FindControl(cntrlName), Label).Text` :- [not getting latest/current value of label, but getting old value]

`txtVal = TryCast(oItem.FindControl(cntrlName), TextBox).Text` :- [getting latest/current value of text-box ]

Comment: You cannot get  a label control's text property in code-behind if it was set on client-side. You need to use a hidden field to capture the text of label on client-side. This hidden field will retain its value on post back and you can access it's value in code-behind instead of label's text property.

Comment: but I am able to get value of textbox, why so?

Comment: text box is an input type element in html and an input type element will always has a value property that is submitted in a post back. however, label is rendered as a span element which has no value property and is not an input type of html element. any thing whose html is like this `<input .... value='dsdssd'.... />` will submit its value to server-side.

Comment: so you can change using JavaScript value of check box, radio button, text box, hidden field and then get this value on server-side,  since all these have a `value` property. if it doesn't have a value property its not going to be submitted. that's how it works in web world.

Comment: okay, thanks for your explanation